# Why the execution time given by ANALYZE (POSTGRESQL) of the same query, is different each time I execute it even if I reset the cache?

Tags: postgresql, caching, indexing, explain

My setup:

- MacOS
- Homebrew
- Postgresql10 installed with brew

To reset the cache I run these commands:

```
brew services stop postgresql@10
brew services start postgresql@10
```

Indeed each time I run the query I don't see `share hit` when I run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)`.

This is what happen:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE key = '...';
```

From query plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable (cost=5.31..663.61 rows=169 width=97) (actual time=1.172..32.475 rows=221 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((key)::text = '...'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=220
  Buffers: shared read=222
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_hash_mytable_key  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=169 width=0) (actual time=0.719..0.719 rows=221 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((key)::text = '...'::text)
        Buffers: shared read=2
Planning time: 6.370 ms
Execution time: 32.527 ms
```

After I re-start postgres and re-run the same query I have:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable (cost=5.31..663.61 rows=169 width=97) (actual time=0.705..42.808 rows=221 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((key)::text = '...'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=220
  Buffers: shared read=222
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_hash_mytable_key  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=169 width=0) (actual time=0.464..0.464 rows=221 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((key)::text = '...'::text)
        Buffers: shared read=2
Planning time: 5.611 ms
Execution time: 42.869 ms
```

As you can see the difference between the two executions is quite big: the first run is about 25% faster that the second one. Probably there are other variables that influence the final result.

Is there a way to have the same execution time every time a run the query? Maybe my current approach to reset the cache is not correct.

The goal is to check the differences in terms of performance between two indexes, but if the executions time is different with the same query plan, after resetting the cache, I cannot check with precision the differences between the performances of two indexes.

Comment: You will never achieve exactly the same query execution times. A reliable benchmark is to run the query several times, reject the first measurement and take the average of the others.

Comment: Is what I'm doing (why I should reject the first measurements?) but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid averaging. Anyway, 25% of difference is quite huge.

Comment: Postgresql relies heavily on the os file cache to and you have done nothing to reset that. And if you did, would that be more realistic, or less realistic?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that attempts to reset the cache will not bring good results. First measurements should be discarded just to get rid of factors related to the preparation of the cache because they depend not only on Postgres itself but on OS as well.

Comment: Should I use `sync && sudo purge`? So, it seems quite difficult to measure the performance between two indexes in this way. How I should make this comparison? Moreover I should make a query that return some rows (how many), forced postgres to read the pages or a query where I expected to return 0 rows? In this way I measure only the reading of the index structure.

Comment: If it is so hard to measure the difference, then maybe the answer is that there is no meaningful difference.

Comment: I meant is difficult to measure the difference in a "clean" way, without cache and other variable involved.

Comment: How many actual rows are there in the table?

Comment: Around 8 million